# Replacement speaker for Black Widow SP 2A?

Tags: speakers

I have a pair of Peaveys with Black Widow speakers. The model is SP 2A with Max Power 300 RMS, 150 continuous, 8 ohm. One of them is blown and I'm trying to find a replacement. I have searched all over the internet and can't figure out a compatible replacement. I know nothing about sound equipment, so forgive me if I sound completely ignorant. I got the system from a friend who told me he had a replacement speaker but apparently can't find it now. Help!

Comment: Is that a 12" or a 15"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer will be dependant on where you live; & as such will be of very limited use to any future users.

Comment: They are 15" speakers.

Comment: Did you search at https://www.peaveyservice.co.uk? Give them a call, and they'll sell you a direct replacement.